# How do I type a disk encryption password using a bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: bluetooth, usability

I'm using a bluetooth keyboard (a [Keychron K8](https://www.keychron.com/products/keychron-k8-tenkeyless-wireless-mechanical-keyboard)) through a USB bluetooth dongle (from [Plugable](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B009ZIILLI)) on Ubuntu 20.10 with an encrypted disk. I connected and trusted the keyboard using `bluetoothctl`. When I restart my computer and get to the disk encryption prompt, my keyboard doesn't connect and I can't type the password unless I plug it in.

Is this because of a bug in bluetooth (I've had trouble with the keyboard not connecting normally before, but it doesn't seem to be an issue right now) or is it because I need to be logged in for bluetooth to work at all?

In a similar vein, can I use a bluetooth keyboard in the BIOS menu or do we simply not have that technology in the year 2020?

Comment: _“can I use a bluetooth keyboard in the BIOS menu?”_ This part is not related to Ubuntu, it depends on your machine’s firmware (BIOS).

Comment: @Melebius are you saying there are motherboards that work with a USB bluetooth dongle? Can you give an example? Will pretty much any motherboard that has WiFi/bluetooth built-in be able to do this? I have a [ASUS X-99-E WS/USB 3.1](https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Motherboards/X99E_WSUSB_31/specifications/)

Comment: I am sorry I have no experience in this field. I personally prefer a cable-connected keyboard and mouse. However, I am pretty sure that iMac’s allow controlling the EFI menu using a Bluetooth keyboard (which is the only one you get with a recent iMac).